# SVG Icon not displaying in IE11

Tags: visualforce, lightning, slds, internet-explorer, svg-icon

SVG icon is not displaying in IE 11 but working in other browsers.

I tried to set absolute path for svg but still not working.

**Updated**  with below code but still not working.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody, '/dist/svg4everybody.legac‌​y.js')}"/
```

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0" applyHtmlTag="false">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

           <apex:stylesheet value="/resource/SLDS213/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css"/> 

             <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody,'/dist/svg4everybody.legac‌​y.js')}"/>

        </head>
        <body style="padding: 0;">
            <div class="slds">
                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container--circle slds-icon-action-description" title="description of icon when needed">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--small">
                    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS213,
      'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account')}"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Description of icon</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <script>
                svg4everybody();
            </script>   
        </body>
  </html>       
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What document mode are you running it in?

Comment: @DanJones Document Mode = Edge(Default)

Comment: The last time I was having issues it was related to the xmlns url. Sorry I don't have anything specific, but it's something to look into.

Answer (score 2):

The script that should be included is the *svg4everybody.legacy.js* one.

Mine was like so :

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody, 'svg4everybody.legacy.js')}"/>
```

You should check in which folder the svg4everybody.legacy.js file is in your static resource. I think it's in dist only.

Try this if svg4everybody.legacy.js file in *dist* folder :

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody, '/dist/svg4everybody.legac‌​y.js')}"/>
```

Comment: I have updated but still not working   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody,'svg4everybody.legacy.js')}"/>

Comment: You should check your static resource.

Comment: Sorry, commented too fast.

My legacy.js file was in the svg4everybody folder . Maybe yours is in the **dist** folder.

Try :

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody, '/dist/svg4everybody.legac‌​y.js')}"/>

Comment: svg4everybody.legac‌​y.js is in  dist folder and I have updated <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.svg4everybody, '/dist/svg4everybody.legac‌​y.js')}"/> but still not working

Comment: I tried it. You're right. It is not working. I'll update you if I find something.